# Move Physical Path of TFS Web Access Website

Tags: iis, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-web-access

I want to move the physical path of TFS Web Access Website (TFS 2015 on Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8) from the default path

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services*

to another partition and path. I couldn't find anything similar on MSDN.

Is this scenario supported? Has anyone ever done that?

Comment: In the initial installation you get to specify another path for the whole TFS server installation. Moving the folder post-installation isn't supported, through I've in the past used a hardlink (junction) to let Windows think the folder was also still under the program files directory. `mklink` is your friend on the commandline.

Comment: @jessehouwing Not to doubt you, but are you positive this is the last word on the matter?

Comment: Thank you. The reasoning behind it is somewhat of a long story...

Comment: I'd love to hear the summary version if you'd be able to share. There are a few folders, the Cache folder for example which can be changed through the config files and the configuration wizard, so if it's a disk-space issue, you could move those.

Comment: The short is politics. Our external HW-Provider doesnt like websites installed on the system partition. All our custom stuff should stay on a separate partition. I tried to change the cache folder but when I try to save the web.config I can't save it. Even with IIS stopped and TFS admin console not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Short: The scenario is not supported.

To move the whole TFS application and websites, you'll need to re-install the application tier and select another root folder during installation. But it is possible that the presence of common libraries from the previous installation will force you to the system partition.

You should be able to change the Cache folder for TFS through the admin console though:

[image]